# TeamCity Finish Build Trigger

Tags: build, teamcity

I've got a build `Travefy :: Build, Unit Test, Package` that I run on every checkin. I have been running it manually to test it as well.

This is a build trigger for `Travefy:: Deploy to Test Environment`. It triggers every time `Travefy :: Build, Unit Test, Package` completes a build.

[image]

As you can see below, even after a successful build of `Travefy :: Build, Unit Test, Package`, the deploy is not triggered. I'm puzzled as to what is going on. Anyone have a clue?

[image]

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but is there a reason you don't want to just make this part of your automatic build and have one build instead of 2 with a trigger between them? If the unit test or packaging failed, the build would stop and wouldn't deploy. Seems like that would be an easier set up if you want to deploy every time the tests pass.

Comment: I was considering that if I couldn't get it to work. I was actually following this guide: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JWGLEEm9Qhg&list=FLH2-AeK6gaxegpKGRG-_W3A&index=1

Comment: Afraid I don't have time to watch all of that. I will say this, though: my team decided to make the deployment a manual kick off rather than automatically triggered. The main reason for that is that we didn't want any unexpected updates to deployed environments. If the deploy happened while the tester was testing, well, that would be weird and might cause some unexpected results. Your needs may vary, though.

Comment: Does the "Deploy to Test Environment" build run if you trigger it manually? I'm just wondering if there's something like a missing Agent Requirement or Build Parameter that's stopping it running.

Comment: how is this still not solved!?!?!?! I am stuck!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `Deploy` has a `Build` as a [dependency](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Build+Chain). In this case if you trigger `Build`, your `Deploy` won't be triggered.
But if you trigger `Deploy` first, then it first will trigger `Build` and will wait for it execution and after that will executed itself.

Also you have a [`Finish Build Triggered`](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+Finish+Build+Trigger) configured. So it could be those two doesn't fit to each other very good. Or you have some misconfiguration in your trigger. But I would recommend to leave trigger and configure everything through build chains -- it is much flexible and solid mechanism.